# Intellij - 3rd party library not being recognized

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

I switched computers recently and have had to set up Intellij on my new laptop. However, the libraries aren't being recognized for some reason.

[image: Here is my class]
<sub>(source: [trillian.im](http://ft.trillian.im/17107e0bd3d38d3147acf89ff7b55b6543455af6/6rXbRVEQk6J5blCpIbdXXtmrr7Ej4.jpg))</sub>

and
[image: here is my project structure]
<sub>(source: [trillian.im](http://ft.trillian.im/17107e0bd3d38d3147acf89ff7b55b6543455af6/6rXbTwPgnq9jRDD1armwTtYXSHBoL.jpg))</sub>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, http://android-wtf.com/2012/09/how-to-configure-actionbarsherlock-with-intellij-idea/ worked for me. I should have imported it as a module rather than a library